# how to change the time format in Linux system

Tags: linux, unix, date

My Linux system has time format of UTC-5:0. How can i change it to UTC+5:30? Using date command i can able to change the time, but not the format

Comment: I  think you probably want superuser.

Comment: That isn't "time format", that is your timezone. And you can set the timezone used via the TZ environment variable (no root required, affects just you).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Calcutta /etc/localtime
```

or

```
cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Colombo /etc/localtime
```

Some distribution provide utilities for that like `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`, `tzselect`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It's better to use

`ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Calcutta /etc/localtime`

Because if you use `cp` and there is some change in the tzdata package you will need to make `cp` again.

Comment: Actually almost all linux distributions nowadays use a copy instead of a symlink. The main reason is, that you have the right timestamps also of early actions that happen before /usr is mounted. This might change again in the future when /usr wont be on a separate partition because udev/systemd/etc. wont support it anymore...

Comment: Yes, i am agree with you, for /usr on a separate partition it's preferably to use a copy.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to change the data time format to UTC+5:30 cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Calcutta /etc/localtime 
or create a softlink.